# Inserting a record with a foreign key. No foreign data exists yet. Database layout issue?

Tags: java, database, database-design, mybatis

I have a database layout where my employee and my next of kin both have an address.

So my keys are laid out like this:

```
Address
----------
addressID


Employee
----------
employeeID
addressID


NextOfKin
----------
nextOfKinID
addressID
```

In MyBatis I have associations set up like this:

```
<resultMap id="employeeMap" type="employee">
    <id column="employeeID" property="employeeID" />

    <association property="address" column="addressID" resultMap="addressMap" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="addressMap" type="address">
    <id column="addressID" property="addressID" />
</resultMap>
```

This is the insert statement. The employeeID is auto incremental so I left it out.

```
<insert id="insert">
INSERT into Employees (addressID)
    VALUES (#{address.addressID})
</insert>
```

Employee object:

```
Employee{
  int employeeID
  Address address
}
```

So when the employee registers and they setup an account they dont have an address yet. So the addressID should be null.

When I insert a record I get an error that the "Column 'addressID' cannot be null".
And when I take it out of the insert statement it throws an error "Field 'addressID' doesn't have a default value".

I want to be able to add an employee and then add the address and the relationship later..

Is this a bad way to lay out the table/relationships? I cant seem to find a way to store the address as null..

Comment: Is `employees.AddressID` defined as NOT NULL in the database?

Answer (score 0):

APC is right: You defined employees.AddressID as NOT NULL in the database. This leads to the error "Column 'addressID' cannot be null". If you want to store a Java null reference in your database you must allow NULL values for that column.

You should also tell MyBatis the SQL-type of address.addressID. So e.g. for type INT change

```
<insert id="insert">
INSERT into Employees (addressID)
    VALUES (#{address.addressID})
</insert>
```

to

```
<insert id="insert">
INSERT into Employees (addressID)
    VALUES (#{address.addressID, jdbcType=NUMERIC})
</insert>
```

See [MyBatis-Documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html):

> "The JDBC Type is required by JDBC for all nullable columns, if null
>   is passed as a value. You can investigate this yourself by reading the
>   JavaDocs for the PreparedStatement.setNull() method."

Answer (score -1):

can you insert a fake address get the value and update the real address using the id from the user?
can you chnge the constraints on the db?

Comment: I was considering that. Another thing I am considering is changing it around so that the address contains all the foreign keys and a type table to show what table the id refers to. Would this be a better design?

Comment: the best is not having constraints if possible.

Comment: the best is not having constraints if possible. search for design of db tables (I will try to find as well). can a user have no address, only one or many addresses? what is the purpose of the foreign key constraint? can you insert the address and fill it later? if there is more then one address might be you should hold table that maps user_id to address ID where the key in that table will be both field...

Comment: the most basic i found is this: [basic relational DB tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)

Comment: "the best is not having constraints if possible" - I love developers who believe this, because they generate so much work for database consultants sorting out the resultant mess.

Comment: @APC, please be more productive and give an idea link or explanation which we will all learn from.